# What is the USB like connector on this PCB?

Tags: pcb, uart, pcb-layers, jtag

I am just jumping into the world of electrical engineering (coming from software development) and I am examining some PCB’s trying to find UART, JTAG connections, etc. I’ve come across a board with a connection that looks like a very small USB connector. I am curious, what does this connector do? Can it be used for debugging and establishing a UART or JTAG connection? Thanks!

[image: USB like connector]

Comment: Looks a bit like pcie x1.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=edge+connector&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Can be pretty much anything.

Comment: There's no USB like connector. A card edge connector maybe. The schematics or service manual should tell what signals it has, whatever boars that is. Any other answer would be guessing.

Comment: It's just a part of a PCB where there are 10 signals (outputs or inputs or power) that will be connected to a proper connector in another board in the same device. It's impossible to say anything more than this.